# Stacey cms project list as index

Tags: php, content-management-system

I use Stancey cms as portfolio for graphic.  I have 4 categories with many projects. I'd like use list of latest  (for example 10) project from all categories. Good solutions will be whatever project list from all categories.

Because now I can set only static content for index page.

I tried use in index variables and collections from http://www.staceyapp.com/documentation/ but without effects.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a nested for that parses all subcategories but shows all items as a same level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had old version and my theme was strange. Default in Stancey homepage looks like in my question. regards

Comment: Yes, that's also true, You just can reuse the code from the default template, good luck!